# CSS3 transform: compensation for children if parent has rotateY

Tags: css, transform, rotatetransform

[Take a look here first](http://jsfiddle.net/QnakF/)

When the div#container is rotateY by a "x" degree, the `<ul>` and and elements inside it will be rotated as well. But I want to all the `<img>` inside each `<li>` to face flat. If I rotateY all the `<li>` by the "-x" deg, it wouldn't work.

Is there a way to achieve and make all the images facing flat toward you, while position along the rotated div#container?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the properties `-webkit-perspective` and `webkit-transform-style` in `ul#looks`, since the parent already has those properties defined.

Also, remove these perspective and transform properties from `ul#looks li` and add this:

```
ul#looks li {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}
```

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/QnakF/1/)

You can see that I commented out the stuff you need to delete.